# Flag counter on top bar showing there are flags, but there aren't any

Tags: bug, 10k-tools, top-bar

I see this since yesterday:

> [image]

Its tooltip says:

> we have posts flagged for moderator attention, perhaps you can help

But when [clicking it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged) I see empty page i.e. no flags:

> [image]

After clicking the number isn't showing for a while but then it come back.

Can the zombie flags please be put to an end? :)

Comment: @Oded thanks, didn't find the dupe! (no proper tag there, will add it)